# Relatively easy way to overlay a seaborn historigram with normal distribution plot

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, seaborn, visualization

Have a dataframe for which I've created a histogram in Seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.histplot(df, bins=100)
```

[image]

I'm also able to create a pdf from its distribution:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = df.describe()
x = np.linspace(a['min'], a['max'])
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, a['mean'], a['std']))
```

[image]

But when I combine them, the scales don't match, so the PDF isn't visible.

Is there a quick way to do this (and the same for a lognormal distribution)?

Comment: Couldn't you scale up your PDF by multiplying it by the total count of items?

Comment: That's what I'd started to do but felt klugey

Comment: Fair, I think @Krishnadev's solution would be the way to go. His solution is essentially dividing the histogram by the count of total items, which still shows useful information (namely the frequency of items per bar)

Answer (score 4):

Your histogram is showing counts, whereas the PDF, by definition, is normalised so that the area under the curve is unity. To show the density instead of counts, pass `stat=density` to `histplot`

```
sns.histplot(df, bins=100, stat='density')
```

See [`histplot` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) for details.

You can also pass `kde=True` if you would like to overlay a KDE instead of plotting the PDF manually.